# Python: splitting a file into two parts

Tags: python, file-io

I currently have a script that breaks off a file into multiple output files of 2 lines each.

```
example, original file:
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

with the output files being:

```
output1.txt      and output2.txt   etc.
AAA                   CCC
BBB                   DDD
```

I was wondering how I could have the code create two output files at once, one taking in the two lines like it does and the other having all the rest of the content in the file, for example..

```
output1.txt      rest1.txt     output2.txt    rest2.txt
AAA               CCC            CCC           AAA
BBB               DDD            DDD           BBB
                  EEE                          EEE
```

This is the code I have so far, which does the first example:

```
splitLen = 2         #  lines per file
outputBase = 'output' # output.1.txt, output.2.txt, etc.

input = open('file.txt', 'r')

count = 0
at = 0
dest = None
for line in input:
    if count % splitLen == 0:
      if dest: dest.close()
      dest = open(outputBase + str(at) + '.txt', 'w')
      at += 1
    dest.write(line)
    count += 1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the file isn't too large to fit in memory, you can convert the input file into a list and then use slicing operations to build the output files.

(edit) to change display values

```
splitLen = 2         #  lines per file
outputBase = 'output%d.txt' # output.1.txt, output.2.txt, etc.
restBase = 'rest%d.txt'

with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    input_list = fp.readlines()
    # to skip empties: input_list = [l for l in fp if l.strip()]

for i in range(0, len(input_list), splitLen):
    iteration = (i/splitLen)
    print 'iter', iteration
    with open(outputBase % iteration, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(''.join(input_list[i:i+splitLen]))
    with open(restBase % iteration, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(''.join(input_list[:i]))
        fp.write(''.join(input_list[i+splitLen:]))
```

Comment: I tried running this and it doesn't create output0.txt, output1.txt, incrementing by one but rather 0, 2, 4 and the last two files were incorrect (rest4.txt was empty and output4.txt was a repeat of output0.txt) - Thoughts? Aside from that, the rest of it works.

Comment: I wasn't sure how you wanted the index - i've changed the code to output files as 1, 2, etc... As for the final files, it could be that you have some blank lines at the end. I included a sample of getting rid of all empty lines.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely also appreciated your solution the most.

Answer (score 1):

I'd structure it like this:

```
with open(infile) as f:
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in f)

pairs = ((i,i+1) for i in range(0,num_lines-1,2))

for i,pair in enumerate(pairs):
     with open('output{}'.format(i),'w') as op, \
          open('rest{}'.format(i),'w') as rest, \
          open(infile) as f:        
         for j, line in enumerate(f):
             if j in pair:
                 op.write(line)
             else:
                 rest.write(line)
```

First, find how many lines are in your input file.  Next, write a generator function that yields pairs (i.e. (0,1) then (2,3) then...) that correspond to the lines you want in your "output" files.  It's pretty straightforward from there.

Comment: With my version of python, 2.6, the comma after as op or as rest is seen as a syntax error (example: the line op, \) - I don't think it'a  missing library. What would be a good equivalent to make the code still work?

Comment: 2.6 is ancient, you should really upgrade your python installation.

Comment: @user3295674: Add to the top of your code, `from __future__ import with_statement`. See [What's New in Python2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement).